# Dispatching Socket.io API response to React Components using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, socket.io, redux-thunk

I'm receiving the data, but the issue is I'm only able to access it inside of the same file **`api.js`**. As I can tell, it's not returning any value. I did a lot of variations of this code snippets. It's either returning the `initial state` or `undefined`. The interesting thing is, if there is an `error`, it would fill out the `error` object. Sorry for so much code, but can someone please help me to successfully implement `socket.io` with `React/ Redux.`

This is what I got so far:

**api.js**
*Here I'm successfully connecting to the API, receiving the data, but I'm not able to use it outside of this file. If a return an object it will be `undefined`, but if I `console.log` it or even `return` a console.log and use the file in other component/ file, the data will show up in my console, but only that way, and only in my console ... can't dispatch the data, and re-use it all over the app that I'm trying to build.*

---

```
import axios from 'axios';
import io from "socket.io-client";

export function fetchData() {

const configUrl = 'API endpoint';
    axios.get(configUrl).then(res => {        
         const socketUrl = res.data.config.liveDistributionSSL;      
            const  socket = io(socketUrl); 

            socket.on('connect', function () {            
                socket.emit('subscribe', {                 
                        subscribeMode: 'topSportBets',                 
                        language: {                    
                             default: 'en'                 
                           },
                       deliveryPlatform: 'WebSubscribe',
                       playerUuid: null,                 
                       subscribeOptions: {                     
                       autoSubscribe: true,                     
                       betCount: 3,      
                       excludeMeta: false,                     
                       resubscriptions: 0,                     
                       fullBetMeta: true,                    
                       browser: {}
                       }           
                   });


                    let relevantData = {}; // Object that I'm trying to assign values to and return


                socket.on('message', async (message) => {

                  switch (message.type) {      

                      case 'state':    // We have all the data needed to show
                        relevantData = await Object.values(Object.values(message.data)[9]);
                        break;

                        case 'currentMatches':
                        // We have matches to update
                        console.log('Matches =>', message.contentEncoding);
                        break;

                        case 'betchange':
                        // We have match bets to update
                        console.log('Match bets =>', message.contentEncoding);
                        break;

                        default: break;
                      }   
                      return relevantData;      
                   });
                   socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Client disconnected"));
               });
          });

        }
```

**actions/index.js**
*This is my main action creator. The code you're seeing was my last attempt to try out a new approach, still the same result.*

---

```
import { GET_DATA, GET_ERROR } from './types';
import { fetchData } from '../api'

export const getDataAsync = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const response = await fetchData();
            dispatch({ type: GET_DATA, payload: response });
    } catch (e) {
            dispatch({ type: GET_ERROR, payload: 'Something went wrong ', e });
        }
    };
```

---

**reducers/data_reducer.js**
*Here I'm making a simple reducer and depending on the `payload` change the `initial state`*

```
import { GET_DATA, GET_ERROR } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  apiData: {},
  errorMessage: {}
};

const dataReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_DATA:
            return { ...state, apiData: action.payload };

        case GET_ERROR:
            return { ...state, errorMessage: action.payload };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default dataReducer;
```

---

**reducers/root_reducer.js**
*Here I'm combining the reducers and later on implement my `root_reducer` to my `store` configuration*

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import dataReducer from './data_reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    allData: dataReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**PrimaryLayoutContainer.js**
*This would be my main `layout` container where I'm implementing routing, display the `PrimaryLayout` component, and where **I'm trying to pass down the values ass props*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PrimaryLayout from "../components/PrimaryLayout";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import * as myData from '../actions';


class PrimaryLayoutContainerComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <PrimaryLayout history={this.props.history}
                               allData={this.props.allData}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        allData: state.allData
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, myData)(PrimaryLayoutContainerComponent));
```

---

**PrimaryLayout.js**
*Where I'm trying to implement the data, all of the routing, and display main components, etc, but here I stopped because I'm not getting the needed data*

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Switch, Route, Redirect, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Favorites from './Favorites';
... a lot of other imports of my components


class PrimaryLayout extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentRoute: '',
            // data: {}
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            currentRoute: nextProps.history.location.pathname
        })
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            currentRoute: this.props.history.location.pathname
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props); // Where i'm trying to get access to the data
    }

    render() {

        const {currentRoute} = this.state;

        return (

            <div className='main-nav'>
            <nav className="topnav">
            <ul>
                <li className={currentRoute === "/favorites" ? "active" : ""}>
                    <Link to="/favorites"><div className='star'></div> Favorites </Link> </li>

                <li className={currentRoute === "/football" ? "active" : ""}>
                    <Link to="/football"><div className='football'></div> Football </Link> </li>

                <li className={currentRoute === "/basketball" ? "active" : ""}>
                    <Link to="/basketball"><div className='basketball'></div> Basketball </Link> </li>

                <li className={currentRoute === "/tennis" ? "active" : ""}>
                    <Link to="/tennis"><div className='tennis'></div> Tennis </Link> </li>

                <li className={currentRoute === "/baseball" ? "active" : ""}>
                    <Link to="/baseball"><div className='baseball'></div> Baseball </Link> </li>

                <li className={currentRoute === "/waterpolo" ? "active" : ""}>
                    <Link to="/waterpolo"><div className='waterpolo'></div> Waterpolo </Link> </li>

            </ul>
          </nav>

                <main>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path='/favorites' component={Favorites} />
                        <Route path='/football' component={Football} />
                        <Route path='/basketball' component={Basketball} />
                        <Route path='/tennis' component={Tennis} />
                        <Route path='/baseball' component={Baseball} />
                        <Route path='/waterpolo' component={Waterpolo} />
                        <Route path='/volleyball' component={Volleyball} />
                        <Route path='/handball' component={Handball} />
                        <Route path='/formula1' component={Formula} />
                        <Redirect to="/football"/>
                    </Switch>
                </main>

            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default PrimaryLayout;
```

---

**index.js**
*This would be my main `index.js` file where I'm configuring the store and rendering elements to the `DOM`*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import './assets/styles/App.css';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/root_reducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

function configureStore() {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  );
}

const myStore = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={myStore}>
   <App />
  </Provider>,
   document.getElementById('root')
 )
```

**NOTE:**

---

Like I said before, I'm successfully connecting to the API endpoint, receiving the necessary data, but I can only manipulate it inside of the same file `api.js`. I Google all day long, but I didn't find anything relevant to my issue. There's a lot of examples with PHP, Java, but not so much with React, Redux, etc ... I never used `Socket.io` before, so please my dear friends, help me ...  :/

**The main question here is:**
How can I successfully implement Scoket.io and use Redux to dispatch the API data throw out all of my main React components, instead of doing it very **DRY**, meaning implement the same logic in every component, and every time to get all of the data, instead of only the relevant one.

**If I can do it in one place (outside of the `api.js` file) I can do it everywhere, and that answer is more than appreciated and will be accepted immediately.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the **`api.js`** file. the `async - await` was causing problems, plus the return statement was in the wrong place. A rookie mistake.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import io from "socket.io-client";

export const fetchData = () => {

let apiData = {}; // Object that I'm trying to assign values to and return
apiData.bets = [];
apiData.matches = [];

const configUrl = 'API URI';
axios.get(configUrl).then(res => {        
        const socketUrl = res.data.config.liveDistributionSSL;      
        const  socket = io(socketUrl); 
        socket.on('connect', function () {            
            socket.emit('subscribe', {                 
                    subscribeMode: 'topSportBets',                 
                    language: {                    
                         default: 'en'                 
                       },
                   deliveryPlatform: 'WebSubscribe',
                   playerUuid: null,                 
                   subscribeOptions: {                     
                   autoSubscribe: true,                     
                   betCount: 3,      
                   excludeMeta: false,                     
                   resubscriptions: 0,                     
                   fullBetMeta: true,                    
                   browser: {}
                   }           
               });

            socket.on('message', (message) => {

              switch (message.type) {      

                case 'state':    // We have all the data needed to show
                apiData.bets = Object.assign(message.data.bets);
                apiData.matches = Object.assign(message.data.matches);
                break;

                // ... etc ...

                default: break;
                  }
               });
               socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Client disconnected"));
           });
      });
      return apiData;
    }
```

---

After that, I implemented a better `store` configuration. I actually made an external file for it, three to be exact, depending on the development progress (dev, stage, prod). Here is the **`configureStore.dev.js`** file:

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {
    createStore,
    applyMiddleware,
    compose
} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/root_reducer';
import reduxImmutableStateInvariant from 'redux-immutable-state-invariant';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(thunk, reduxImmutableStateInvariant()),
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
        )
    );
}
```

---

And finally what I did to make it all work, I changed the **`PrimaryLayoutContainerComponent.js`** to look like this. And with all that simple, but important changes I was able to access all the relevant data as its being updated in real-time throughout the entire app.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import PrimaryLayout from "../components/PrimaryLayout";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import * as myData from '../actions';


// Since this is our Primary Layout Container here we in addition to mapping state to props also
// are dispatching our props and binding our action creators, also using 'withRouter' HOC
// to get access to the history object’s properties and make it easy to navigate through our app.

class PrimaryLayoutContainerComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <PrimaryLayout history={this.props.history}
                               allData={this.props.allData}
                               getDataAsync={this.props.actions.getDataAsync}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {allData: state.allData.apiData}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators({...myData}, dispatch)
    };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PrimaryLayoutContainerComponent));
```

*A little sidenote: I always answer my own questions instead of just deleting them with n I find the resolution myself. I do that for the simple fact that it might help someone in the future.*